# WebM not falling back to Flash in browsers not supporting it with mediaelement.js

Tags: html, html5-video, mediaelement.js, webm

I am trying to use mediaelement.js to show videos in HTML5 with fallback to Flash if browsers don't support it.
It says that when a codec is not supported it will fallback automatically, but it doesn't and only shows me an image. If I remove the WebM line, then it shows me the Flash player.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<video class="videos" width="560" height="315" controls="controls" poster="img/img.jpg">
                        <source type="video/webm" src="videos/video.webmvp8.webm" />

                        <object width="560" height="315" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
                            <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
                            <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=img.jpg&file=videos/video.flv" />
                            <!-- Image as a last resort -->
                            <img src="img/img.jpg" width="560" height="315" title="No se encontr&oacute; posibilidad de reproducir el video" />
                        </object>
        </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "last resort" img element should be outside the object element and beneath it.

Comment: Copied that code from mediaelementjs.com. Anyway, width the img outside the object element I'm still getting a download message for the webM when I click on the image instead of the flash movie.